# Software center

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening)

Hi I am a newbie and have the following problem, any help would be greatly appreciated

The software center is opening with a blank screen

Can you please help

Comment: Can you provide more information?. Which Ubuntu version are you using?. Can you post an screenshot?. How long do you wait for it to open?. If you know how to open it from a terminal, can you post any messages that it prints to the terminal?.

Comment: It happens frequently for me too ,just reboot it will return to original state

Answer (score 1):

Wait for some time. It will load, first time it might take more time. If you want to know the status do this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after closing software center